# Best alternative to set a PostgreSQL schema using PHP PDO

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo

I am using PHP PDO to access a PostgreSQL database with various schemas, so first i create a connection and then i set the correct schema, like below:

```
$Conn = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=db', 'user', 'pass');

$result = $Conn->exec('SET search_path TO accountschema');

if ( ! $result) {
    die('Failed to set schema: ' . $Conn->errorMsg());
}
```

Is this a good practice? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In order to specify the default schema you should set the [search_path](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-SEARCH-PATH) instead.

```
$Conn->exec('SET search_path TO accountschema');
```

You can also set the default search_path per database user and in that case the above statement becomes redundant.

```
ALTER USER user SET search_path TO accountschema;
```