# Table not found in PHP-PDO environment with Driver PGSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

The connection to the PostGreSQL-DB works without error.
The SQL-Statement

```
select * from sessions;
```

returns the error "Relation sessions does not exist".

If the following statement is exececuted at this place:

```
select * from pg_catalog.pg_tables where tablename = 'sessions';
```

than one record is found:

```
schemaname: appgeenlabor, tablename: sessions,
tableowner: forum, hasIndexes: true, 
hasrules: false, hastriggers: true, 
rowsecurity: false
```

The database is connected with user "forum".

Which conditions can avoid the selection of the table session?

Note: the table sessions has been created by the tool "pgloader" which converts a MySql table into a PostGreSQL table.

Comment: Do you instruct PHP to use the `appgeenlabor` schema in some place?

Comment: Qualify the table name with the schema name, i.e. `select * from appgeenlabor.sessions;`

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: Where can I "order" this scheme?

Comment: @Stefanov.sm: In this case the error message is: Relation appgeenlabor.sessions does not exist.

Comment: It seems the only way to set a default schema is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714096/best-alternative-to-set-a-postgresql-schema-using-php-pdo

Comment: Show us your code, there is no reason to set a default schema. You can use any schema, as long as it exits in your database and you mention this in your query.